# Use my system's gems instead of an RVM gemset on a pre-bundler Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I have several old (pre-bundler / pre-rvm) Rails projects that use my system's gems.

Now I've installed RVM to ride the latest Rails version, but my old applications are now using a gemset: (I'm not sure exactly what I did to make this happen)

```
~/rails_apps/rapgenius >: echo $GEM_HOME
/Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302
```

I want to use my system's gems by default, and, if I have an `.rvmrc` file in a directory, I want to use the gemset it specifies in that directory. Like this:

```
~/rails_apps/reader2000 >: cat .rvmrc 
rvm 1.9.2@reader2000
~/rails_apps/reader2000 >: echo $GEM_HOME
/Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried `rvm use system --default`

Comment: Just tried it and now I get this: https://gist.github.com/1500700 (something seems messed up!)

Comment: Your rvm version 1.0.9 is super old (sept 2010) try updating your rvm install. think current is 1.10.0

Comment: Updating RVM and doing `rvm use system --default` seems to have worked! However, I'm still getting some wonky shit for `rvm info` and `echo $GEM_HOME` (however, `gem list` works fine): https://gist.github.com/05d02357eed0a695fac7. Thoughts? (Either way, add an answer so I can accept it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
rvm use system --default
```